# Transform data from one column to multiple columns in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two columns of data in csv format as shown below from a prediction server.The first column is an index position for each variable for each prediction. Therefore new data starts at index 1.

```
1,2.0
2,1.5
3,1.4
1,1.1
2,2.0
3,1.5
4,2.0
5,1.6
1,2.0
2,4.0

.
.
.
```

I would like to have the data in this format instead,

```
2.0,1.1,2.0
1.5,2.0,4.0
1.4,1.5
    2.0
    1.6
```

For ease of work, The empty 'cells' can be filled with zeros or # e.g

```
2.0,1.1,2.0
1.5,2.0,4.0
1.4,1.5,0
0,  2.0,0
0,  1.6,0
```

Someone with an elegant way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: it's not clear why the last 5.0 goes in the 3rd column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to transpose it with Array#transpose:

```
# first get a 2d representation of the data
rows = CSV.read(fn).slice_before{|row| "1" == row[0]}.map{|x| x.map{|y| y[1]}}

# we want to transpose the array but first we have to fill empty cells
max_length = rows.max_by{|x| x.length}.length
rows.each{|row| row.fill '#', row.length..max_length}

# now we can transpose the array
pp rows.transpose

["2.0", "1.1", "2.0", "5.0"],
["1.5", "2.0", "4.0", "#"],
["1.4",  "1.5", "#", "#"],
["#", "2.0", "#", "#"],
["#", "1.6", "#", "#"], 
["#", "#", "#", "#"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
require 'csv'

# read csv contents from file to array
rows = CSV.read("path/to/in_file.csv")

res = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}
rows.each do |(key, val)|
  res[key] << val
end

# write to output csv file
CSV.open("path/to/out_file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  # sort res hash by keys, map to have array of values and add to csv
  res.sort_by{|k, v| k}.map{|k, v| v}.each do |r|
    csv << r
  end
end
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! Unfortunately it does not seem to work for this dataset... any ideas why? http://pastebin.com/2CcEJf6t

Comment: Why this does not work? It collected all the data to csv in a format you described. Of course there are more columns, than in your example of the output csv.

Comment: The output data does not correspond with the initial data. see the paste here: http://pastebin.com/CUiVHaFd